# .ashx and .axd do not load

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I'm running a CMS on my local machine with the following:

1. IIS 7.5
2. Windows 7 Pro
3. App Pool is set to Integrated mode and .NET V 4.0.30319
4. I do have .NET 4.5 installed by my website (CMS) targets 4.0 and I've built for 4.0

I have problem that I cannot reproduce but every few page requests, the pages stop responding.  Digging into the issue a little further, I noticed using the Chrome developer tools that when this happens it's ALWAYS because of `WebResource.axd`, `ScriptResource.axd`, or one of the other `.ashx` handlers.

Here is a screenshot of the Chrome Developer Tools where the scrips are failing:

[image]

It looks like they just time out.  I'm unable to find any entries in the event viewer and I'm not sure where else to from here.  Sometimes I have no issues other times, this manifests itself.  Drop a comment if there is something more I can provide.

Comment: You should inspect the response returned for the failing requests to see if they contain an error. If they don't, you can likely enable remote errors for the site or access it locally on the server.

Comment: Did you fix this? I'm having the same issue. Seen some suggestions that it's AVG related, others suggest it's a Telerik issue. I can't fix it and it seems to be getting worse.

Comment: @Sean No, we still have this issue at times.  We did have another issue for a few weeks which was causing request timeouts and that was related to AVG (specific AVG components like link scanner being installed on the web server).  We aren't using Telerik for anything so I can't comment on that.